# Update iOS 5.1.1 on iPad 1 to at least iOS 6

Tags: ios, ipad, software-update

I have read many post about updating an iPad 1 (iOS 5.1.1) to iOS 8 but all I need at the moment is to update my iPad 1 to at least iOS 6. Is there any way I can update it to iOS 6? No jail breaking or anything, just a normal way of updating.